# Asignar valores operables a las letras del alfabeto

Tags: javascript, string

De esta manera:

```
a=4 b=2 c=8 ... ... h=6 i=3 ...
var palabra=prompt("di lo que quieras");
Input del usuario: "Hi!"
```

No se como abordar esto:

```
var result= h+i??????
alert(result);
```

Y dependiendo del string obtenido, después sumar dichos valores.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existen varias formas de resolver este problema. Te propongo una utilizando las bondades de JavaScript:

```js
var mapa = { "a":4, "b":2, "c":8, "h":6, "i":3 }; //agregar las necesarias
var palabra=prompt("di lo que quieras");
var result = palabra.toLowerCase()
    .split('')
    .map(x => mapa[x] || 0 )
    .reduce( (x, y) => x + y);
alert(result);
```

Explicación:

- `mapa`: mapa donde podemos colocar los caracteres y sus valores numéricos
- `palabra`: nombre de la variable que almacena el texto ingresado por el usuario.
- `toLowerCase`: función para colocar todos los caracteres en minúscula.
- `split('')`: creará un arreglo con cada caracter de la cadena de texto.
- `map`: función que va a transformar (*mapear*) los elementos del arreglo al aplicar la función que coloquemos dentro
- `x => mapa[x] || 0`: Se utiliza un lambda que es para evitar declarar funciones adicionales en el código, de esta manera se reduce el código y se vuelve más legible.

  - `x` es el argumento de la función.
  - `=>` indica el inicio de la función.
  - `mapa[x] || 0` va a obtener el elemento `[x]` que se encuentra declarado en `mapa`. Este debería ser un número. Si se utiliza un elemento como `!` que no está en el mapa, esto devolverá `undefined`. Para transformar `undefined` a 0 se utiliza el artificio `numero || 0`
- `reduce`: función que va a reducir todos los elementos del arreglo. Se utiliza para obtener un resultado único de todos los elementos de un arreglo.
- `(x,y) => x + y`: Un lambda que recibe dos argumentos y devuelve la suma de los mismos.

Comment: excelente respuesta

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias! Funciona perfecto, muy bien explicado.

Answer (score 1):

NOTA>> Fijate la respuesta de @LuiggiMendoza que utiliza algunas características mas nuevas de JavaScript, esta version es para navegadores anteriores.

Supongamos que puedes poner los valores en un objeto en lugar de variables independientes:

```js
var diccionario = { a:1, b:2, c:8, h:6, i:3 };

var input = "hi"; // agrega aqui el prompt

var resultado = 0;

for(var i in input) {
  var c = input.charAt(i);
  if (c in diccionario) {
    resultado += diccionario[c]
  }
}

alert(resultado);
```

Luego para cada carácter en tu entrada, tomas el valor del "mapa" de valores y los sumas en un bucle.

Comment: Buena respuesta, apuntando a "la antigua"