# Sumar dígitos de un string

Tags: javascript, string

Lo que quiero es que si el número introducido por el usuario tiene más de un dígito, dichos dígitos se sumen, y que devuelva siempre una sola cifra.

Por ejemplo, si el usuario introduce `14`, devuelva `5`.

Otro ejemplo es que si el usuario escribe `87`, la suma debe ser `15` pero debe volver a sumarse y el resultado final sería `6`.

```
var numero=prompt("introduzca un número");

if(numero>=10){

}

else{
  alert(numero);
}
```

Comment: Hola Nian_cat. La pregunta que publicas es muy similar a [tu anterior pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/4006/227), con la única diferencia de que no necesitas mapear los caracteres a un valor numérico. Te recomiendo que por favor intentes resolverlo y tu pregunta se oriente a qué dificultades tienes mientras lo solucionas.

Comment: Efectivamente Luiggi, es la continuación. Voy a intentarlo, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué debería devolver en casos como por ejemplo 87?¿Debería ser 15 (8+7) o 6 (8+ 7=15; 1+5=6)?

Comment: 87. 8+7=15. 1+5=6. Consiste en reducir todo a una única cifra.

Comment: @Nian_cat pero conociendo la tecnica de como sumar los valores de una cifra puedes aplicar en el while hasta que el valor sea inferior a 10, o sea repites la operacion tantas veces como sea necesario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basado en [mi respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/4008/227) a [la pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/4006/227):

```js
    var numero = parseInt(prompt("introduzca un número"));
    while (numero >= 10) {
        numero = numero.toString()
            .split('')
            .map(x => parseInt(x) )
            .reduce( (x, y) => x + y);
    }
    alert(numero);
```

Comment: Luiggi, te voy a poner un monumento, muchísimas gracias.

Comment: De nada @Nian_cat

Comment: GESPER y LEANDRO, vuestras respuestas TAMBIÉN son CORRECTAS. ¡Muchas gracias a todos!

Answer (score 3):

La idea es hacer una función recursiva, la respuesta de @Leandro iba bien encaminada pero le faltaron unos puntos claves.

```js
var cadena = prompt("Introduzca un número");
var numero = parseInt(cadena);

//Llamamos a la función recursiva
reduce(numero);

function reduce(num){
  if(numero >= 10){

    var suma = 0;
    for (var c in cadena) 
     suma += parseInt(cadena[c]);
      
      if(suma.toString().length > 1){

        //Si sigue siendo de más de un dígito, reseteamos las variables e iniciamos de nuevo
        numero = suma;
        cadena = suma.toString();
        reduce(suma);
      }else{
        alert(suma);
      }
  }
  else{
    alert(numero);
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var numero = prompt("introduzca un número");

if (numero >= 10) {
  var res = numero.split("");

  var arrayLength = res.length;
  numero = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    var a = Number(res[i]);
    numero = numero + a;
  }
  alert(numero);
} else {
  alert(numero);
}
```

Esto resuelve el problema de sumar tus numeros, pero no resuelve el hecho de que siempre quieras un solo digito, por ejemplo si coloco 99 la suma resultaria en 18.

Answer (score 1):

Podría ser algo como esto:

```js
var cadena = prompt("introduzca un número");

var numero = parseInt(cadena);

if(numero >= 10){

  var suma = 0;
  for (var c in cadena) 
    suma += parseInt(cadena[c]);

  alert(suma);
}
else
{
  alert(numero);
}
```

---

Si se quiere que sea un solo dígito solo es cuestión de usar el `while`:

```js
var numero = parseInt(prompt("introduzca un número"));

if(numero >= 10){

 var suma = 0;
 
 do{

   suma = sumar(numero.toString());
   numero = suma;
     
 }while(suma >= 10);

  alert(suma);
}
else
{
  alert(numero);
}

function sumar(cadena){

  var suma = 0;
  for (var c in cadena) 
    suma += parseInt(cadena[c]);

  return suma;
}
```

Comment: Esto no resuelve el problema, él quiere que el resultado final sea siempre una sola cifra.

Comment: @Gepser si lo se, eso lo agrego en el comentario, pero la tecnica es la misma, solo falta poner el bloque que suma las cifras dentro de un while para que lo repita hasta que sea un numero de un digito

Answer (score 0):

Esta sería una forma basada en tu código original:

```js
var numero = prompt("Introduzca un número");
var valorIntroducido = parseInt(numero);

if(valorIntroducido >= 10){ //más de 2 digítos.
    var suma = 0;
    for (var i in numero){             
     suma += parseInt(numero[i]);     
   }
   alert("Resultado : " +suma);
}else{//1 digito
    alert("Resultado (1 digíto): " +valorIntroducido);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mi respuesta va encaminada a hacer un parse del número en el parámetro y utilizar recursividad una vez obtenido el número para obtener la suma de todos sus digitos.

```
function sumarDigitos(numero) {
    return numero == 0 ? numero : sumarDigitos(numero/10) + (numero%10);
}

var sumaNumero = parseInt(cadenaNumero);
```

Para retornar un único dígito...

```
while (sumaNumero > 9) {
    sumaNumero = sumarDigitos(sumaNumero)
}
```

Para obtener una cadena el único dígito...

```
var sumaCadena = sumaNumero.toString();
```